# All emails are sent from the same address

Tags: email

I've noticed recently that when you send an email via Actions->Send Email, it does not show as being from the address you are logged in with or the one you choose from the drop-down. Instead it always comes from the same address (presumably one that is configured globally somewhere).

The reply-to address is correct, but the from address is not.

There is nothing in the bug tracker about it. Is anyone else having this problem? I have not consciously changed any email settigs... I'm on civi 4.7.22 on Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - yes that sounds like a regression. This is working fine in 4.6.28 - I just confirmed that in 4.6.28 the From is (correct) the Email that I am selecting from the From list - and not the default From as configured in:

```
civicrm/admin/options/from_email_address?reset=1
```

Open a JIRA ticket for it to try get some attention to this issue. Label it with **regression** - and any detail you may have e.g. do you remember when this was last working?

Comment: Done. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21035

Comment: @naomi I'll get in and label it verified; unfortunately I don't know too much about Email handling in CiviCRM so can't help fix this.

Comment: and done - need more characters...

Comment: This is still not working although the issue is marked fixed https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21035

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it isn't defaulting to the site default address, but to the address used to authenticate with the SMTP server, which is in our case Gmail.

I think it is actually Gmail that is changing the From address, because the one that Civi is attempting to send from is not verified as an alternative address to send from that account.